# finding the slope of a line connecting two given Terminal points

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

Say that Point X is the terminal point of Angle $\alpha$  and Point Y is the terminal point of $\beta$ on the unit circle.

**"Terminal point", in this case, is the point that is obtained by rotating counterclockwise from point (1,0) on the unit circle.**

Point X is in the first quadrant. Point Y is in the second quadrant.

$\tan \alpha = 1$ and $\tan \beta = -7$. Find the slope of $\overline{XY}$.

What I have so far:

$\alpha$ is $\frac{\pi}{4}$. since cos x = the x coordinate of the terminal point, would I have to find $cos \frac{\pi}{4}$ to get $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$?

I am not sure what $\beta$ is in reduced terms because doing $arc tan(-7)$ results in -1.4288999... but finding the cos of that is $\frac{1}{5\sqrt{2}}$ (or is it $-\frac{1}{5\sqrt{2}}$?).

I am assuming that they both will have the same y coordinate, so would the slope be $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} + \frac{1}{5\sqrt{2}} = \frac{3\sqrt{2}}{5}$?

Comment: Point $Y$ is in the second quadrant, I think (what's about $B$ ?). Moreover the slope of a line, not of a point $\dots$

Comment: @TonyPiccolo The slope of XY, so what I was referring to was if there were $X=(x_1, y_1)$ and $Y=(x_2, y_2)$, the slope would be $\frac{(y_2)-(y_1)}{(x_2)-(x_1)}$

Comment: Sure and the abscissa of $Y$ is negative.

Comment: @TonyPiccolo abscissa? the x coordinate of the terminal point Y?

Comment: Yes. I used that name to avoid confusion.

Comment: @TonyPiccolo ah, ok. is $\frac{3\sqrt{2}}{5}$ correct?

Comment: How did you get that value ?

Comment: @TonyPiccolo see above in my original post

Comment: @TonyPiccolo nevermind, it's incorrect. do you see any mistakes in my original post?

Comment: As it stands, this question doesn't make sense. I need to have particular points $X$ and $Y$ on the respective terminal sides of the angles in order to have a well-defined $\overline{XY}$.

Comment: Upload a picture can clear things up a bit. I suspect that X and Y are on the circumference of the same (probably the unit) circle.

Comment: @Mick: Ted helped me with the problem in the chat, the misunderstanding was in what I meant by "terminal point", which in this case, is the point that is rotated counterclockwise from point (1,0) on the unit circle.

Comment: what exactly does "Point $X$ is the terminal point of $\alpha$" mean? What is $\alpha$?

Comment: Good. That is exactly what I have guessed.

Comment: @robjohn: $\alpha$ is the angle in the unit circle.

Comment: @MathyPerson: so $X$ is the point on the unit circle with angle $\alpha$: $(\cos(\alpha),\sin(\alpha))$ and $Y=(\cos(\beta),\sin(\beta))$? That is not clear from the question.

Comment: @robjohn: Yes, that is correct. I will edit my op to avoid further confusion.

Comment: In any case the system $$\begin {cases} a^2+b^2=1 \\ \\ \dfrac ba=k \end {cases}$$ has two solutions $(a,b)$. Choose the right one for $k=1$ and $k=-7$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $X$ and $Y$ are on the unit circle, we have
$$
X=(\cos(\alpha),\sin(\alpha))
$$
and
$$
Y=(\cos(\beta),\sin(\beta))
$$
The slope of $\overline{XY}$ would be
$$
\frac{\sin(\beta)-\sin(\alpha)}{\cos(\beta)-\cos(\alpha)}
$$
Since $\tan^2(x)+1=\sec^2(x)=\frac1{\cos^2(x)}$, we have
$$
\cos(x)=\frac{\pm1}{\sqrt{1+\tan^2(x)}}
$$
Also $\sin(x)=\tan(x)\cos(x)$. Therefore,
$$
\sin(x)=\frac{\pm\tan(x)}{\sqrt{1+\tan^2(x)}}
$$
The choice of $\pm$ depends on the quadrant. Use $+$ in quadrants I and IV and $-$ in quadrants II and III.

Answer (score 0):

The secant ( not tangent) joining X and Y intersects x-axis at an angle $ > \pi/2 $ but $ < \pi $ in second quadrant in an anti-clockwise direction.  Hence its tangent should be negative. The angular bisector of these directions is perpendicular to this secant line.The bisector makes $ (\alpha + \beta )/2 $ to x-axis.

$$ slope = \tan ( \pi/2 +(\alpha + \beta )/2) = -\cot ((\alpha + \beta )/2) $$

To further simplify use tan of half angle with Trig formula of double angle $(\alpha + \beta ) $ on right hand side:

$$ tan\, x = \dfrac {(1 - cos\, 2 x)}{sin\, 2 x} $$

to take it further from there.